# python sort on extension / Name of the file

Tags: python

I'm working on a script for a school project:

```
search_folder = raw_input('Choose Directory')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_folder):
       for file in files:
               pathname = os.path.join(root, file)
               print pathname
               print os.path.getsize(pathname)
```

How can I sort the output on Extension?

Comment: Consider using the built-in `sorted()` function with an appropriate key function, eg something using the  `os.path.splitext()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sorting filenames

Use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with an [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) in the *sort-by* `key` parameter.

### Example

```
import os

search_folder = '/Users/temp/'

results = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_folder):
       for f in files:
            results.append(os.path.join(root, f))

sorted_results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1])

for path in sorted_results:
    print path
    print os.path.getsize(path)
```

---

```
/Users/temp/.DS_Store
6148
/Users/temp/.localized
0
/Users/temp/profile.png
81168
/Users/temp/IMG_0115.xcf
113212
/Users/temp/profile.xcf
535202
```

### Other considerations & suggestions

#### Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

You can also use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (for speed and readability) to walk the files:

```
results = [os.path.join(root, f) 
               for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_folder) 
                   for f in files]
```

#### Memory efficient sorting

Sort without storing [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003624/python-sort-on-extension-name-of-the-file/30003951#comment48126984_30003951) from @PM2Ring:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_folder):
    for f in sorted(files, key=lambda x: tuple(reversed(os.path.splitext(x)))):
        pathname = os.path.join(root, f)
        print pathname 
        print os.path.getsize(pathname)
```

Comment: It's not good to use `file` as a variable name in Python 2, since it shadows the built-in `file` type (similar to using `list`, `str`, etc as a variable name).

Comment: I suspect that tartaarsap wants to sort each directly separately, rather than bundling them all together into `results` and then sorting. If so, you don't need to build a `results` list, since you can apply `sorted()` directly to the `files` list generated by `os.walk()`. Also, you could sort by name as well as extension with a fancier key function, eg `ext_key = lambda x: tuple(reversed(os.path.splitext(x)))`

Comment: I used `file` to keep the code as similar as possible to @tartaarsap code, but you are absolutely right!  Also good idea to sort inline vs stored.